# UNNotificationTrigger about fireDate

Tags: triggers, ios10, unnotificationtrigger

In iOS 10 I use new frameWork UNNotification .When setting UNNotificationTrigger I want to set a fire Date on UNNotification. But I can't find set a fire Date in  UNNotificationTrigger's properties. So How can i set a fire Date in UNNotificationTrigger. I want set a fire Date in UNNotificationTrigger, how can i set

Comment: Add some details and efforts you have put in. Unless nobody will be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of triggers in User Notifications framework:

1. UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger - Used for creating a notification with a set interval time:

   Fire in 30 minutes (60 seconds times 30) ,

   ```
   let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (30*60), repeats: false)
   ```
2. UNCalendarNotificationTrigger- Used for creating a notification at a certain date as in your case and for repeating with specific criteria:

   ```
   let date = DateComponents()
   date.hour = 8
   date.minute = 30 
   let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
   ```

The solution (Swift 3) for you would be to convert your date to a dateComponent and this can be done by:

```
import UserNotifications

var newComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)
```

Comment: There is a third type of trigger in iOS 10 `UNLocationNotificationTrigger`